# How to choose where to sell my sfx?

Tags: effects, selling, library, royalties

This article I found today. I think that might be of interest. You what is your opinion about that?

[Selling Sound Effects: How to Choose Where to Sell – Part 1](http://www.jetstreaming.org/2011/02/18/selling-sound-effects-how-to-choose-where-to-sell-part-1/)

[Selling Sound Effects: How to Choose Where to Sell – Part 2](http://www.jetstreaming.org/2011/02/23/selling-sound-effects-how-to-choose-where-to-sell-part-2/)

Answer (score 1):

Anyone know if such website exists which is non-profit or very small profit for the service provider, but allows selling & purchasing samples?

There's probably a dilemma in offering such service without taking a share of the sales to cover hosting & support costs, but I still wanted to ask, because I think such community for recordists and sound designers would be brilliant and fair.

Like freesound.org, but where sounds are exchanged for money (or for other sounds), can be fully licensed (and not CC or public domain) and the profits go to the recordists and sound designers that deserve them.

I feel bad for purchasing from sites that pass only a fraction of the profits to the content providers. And big downloadable libraries are not as flexible as online libraries with previewing.

Comment: You can try Sampleism.com

Comment: Thanks. Looking for more unprocessed and raw material and non-musical sounds for sound design purposes though. Currently mainly using Soundsnap.com, but I dislike the policy of passing only 50% as royalties, afaik. Although the library is great.

Comment: I don't know of any marketplace that doesn't take a cut. That's kind of the price you pay to be part of a good one. I think AudioJungle has a decent sound effects selection. They take a standard cut, but their market is large and busy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compare prices of airbornesound.com (author of Selling Sound Effects: How to Choose Where to Sell) and other independent sound effects libraries? I found it completely out of reasonable range.
Just look at http://designingsound.org/sfx-independence/. There are much better, complex and professional libraries for much better prices.